# svg on older IE browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, vml, polyfills

I am building floor plans in svg format and I am looking for a polyfill to support older browsers: IE7, IE8 and IE9 quirksmode.

I have heard about [svgweb](https://code.google.com/p/svgweb/), but I am not sure if it is still maintained as the last version is 2 years old. Also I'd rather not use a proprietary technology like Flash. I have also found [svg2vml](https://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/), but it is 3 years old yet marked as work in progress.

All I need in my case is to draw shapes (circles and polygons), and detect hover and click events. Is there a simple and solid polyfill for my specific requirement?

Comment: Is IE7 worth it? http://theie7countdown.com/

Comment: @epascarello my understanding is that these countdowns are only for public sites, not corporate intranets.

Comment: @ErikDahlström thx, but that question is 4 years old and doesn't really address my concern about outdated code. Also, the accepted answer actually offers a workaround (abstract svg) rather than a direct answer.